# Intuition for following sequence theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm learning sequences and this is one of the theorems in my textbook:

> If $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L$ and the function $f$ is continuous at $L$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(a_n)=f(L)$ .

First off, I am confused by the function $f$ being continuous at L. L is a y-value but I am used to continuity statements of the form "[insert function] being continuous at [insert x-value]. Secondly, what intuition is there for this statement. I can't seem to find any intuition.

Comment: $L$ is not a "$y$-value". The continuity of $f$ is defined in points that's living in its domain (that is, "$x$-values")

Comment: By the way, $L$ is the $x$-value and $f(L)$ is the $y$-value (maybe this is what confuses you).

Comment: Definition of continuity.

Comment: @xbh How do I get from $\lim_{x\to L}f(x)=f(L)$ to $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(a_n)=f(L)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intuition is that if a sequence converges to some limit, then the sequence of values of a *continuous* function on that sequence also converges to the function evaluated at the limit; this makes sense because for "nice" functions, "converging sequences on the $x$-axis" mean "converging sequences on the $y$-axis".

Proof: $f$ is continuous at $L$ means that $\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta$ such that $|x-L|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(L)|<\epsilon$, but $x_k\to L$ means that $\forall \epsilon', \exists K$ such that $k\geq K \implies |x_k-L|<\epsilon'$. Take $\epsilon'=\delta$ (the $\delta$ from the continuity of $f$); then we have that $k\geq K \implies |x_k-L|<\delta \implies |f(x_k)-f(L)|<\epsilon$.